# Why random numbers from fitted distribution do not have the same distribution as the sample data?

Tags: distributions, random-generation, fitting

I have a data set and I would like to fit a t distribution on it. I use R or Python to feed into my data, and I get the degrees of freedom, the location and the scale parameters.

After that, I generated random t distributed numbers with the parameters I got from my data set.
Then I compared these random numbers with the original data using the Kolmogorov Smirnov and the Anderson-Darling tests. Both rejected the Null hypothesis.

I would like to know why this happens and what could I do about it?

Comment: Does it happen with any sample you generate or only sometimes? How often it does happen?

Comment: It happens with every sample.

Comment: You might try my online open source Python statistical distribution fitter and see if it can suggest a scipy continuous distribution to consider, the link is http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/ with source code links at the bottom of the web page.

Comment: How large is the sample?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan It has almost 2000 observations

Comment: You can run a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of fit to the t distribution without simulating a t sample and this would be more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to suggest that your original data is not, in fact, t-distributed. You could fit a t-distribution to literally any data set, that doesn't mean it will describe your data well. The fact that your tests reject the null hypothesis shows that there is a mismatch between the distribution of your data and your fitted t-distributed samples.

Maybe try to fit a different distribution to your data, since it is significantly different from t-distributed.